# Can't write to a knockout observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having a very strange bug when I am trying to update a user's address.  I have this simplified address object with two fields, both observables:

```
stateProvince.name = ko.observable("");
stateProvince.code = ko.observable("");
```

Now, when I try to update both of these later, this is the effective program execution in dev tools:

```
stateProvince.name("New York");
stateProvince.code("NY");
```

but the second line does not actually change the value of the state code.  no exceptions occur, attempting to change it in dev tools does not work, and the strangest part is that everything that fails when changing the code works fine when changing the name.  What conditions could cause a knockout observable from failing to update with no errors?  I am trying to extend an existing codebase but my searching has not revealed anything that would differentiate these two objects.

Comment: your best bet is to try to reproduce it in jsFiddle. From this code it looks fine. If I had to guess, I would say that your `code` is bound to a `select`. If you are using the `value` binding (usually with `options`) on the select element, then Knockout tries to enforce that your observable's value corresponds to an option.  Maybe "NY" does not match an option.

Comment: it is bound to a select!  NY is an option but it may not exist yet as the observable array the options are being generated from hasn't been created yet.  thank you, i will add a callback for when the select options are populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comment to answer:

If `code` is bound to a `select` and you are using the `value` binding (usually with `options`), then Knockout tries to enforce that your observable's value corresponds to an option. Make sure the your initial values corresponds to an option.

If your options are getting populated later, then you will need to either re-populate the selected value, or you can pre-populate it on the initial load with something like:

```
this.code = ko.observable(data.code);

//pre-populate with the one matching value
this.codeOptions = ko.observableArray([data.code]);
```